# How to copy cells in Excel like hyperlinks from one Book to another using Python?

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink, copy, openpyxl

I need to copy cells like hyperlinks from one Excel file to another. I can't find anything relating to this problem. I can copy cells values but it's not what I need.

I tried to modify some examples of coping cells from one book to another, but it wasn't success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the value in each cell from a source workbook (in this example 'foo1.xlsx') to a new workbook (destination workbook) and have the destination cells link back to the source cells

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.hyperlink import Hyperlink

source_path = "foo1.xlsx"
source_sheet = 'Sheet1'

source_wb = load_workbook(source_path)
source_ws = source_wb[source_sheet]

### Create a new workbook and worksheet to copy data to and rename the 
### sheet to 'Sheet1'
destination_wb = Workbook()
destination_ws = destination_wb.active
destination_ws.title = 'Sheet1'

### Loop thru the rows and cells in the source sheet
for row in source_ws.iter_rows():
    for source_cell in row:
        cell_coord = source_cell.coordinate

        # Skipping empty cells.
        # Otherwise these cells in the destination workbook will be
        # filled with the source filename.
        if source_cell.value is None:
            continue

        ### Create hyperlink to source cell 
        hyperlink = Hyperlink(target=source_path,
                              ref=cell_coord,
                              location = f'{source_sheet}!{cell_coord}')
        ### Copy source cell value to the destination sheet
        destination_ws.cell(source_cell.row, source_cell.column).value = source_cell.value
        ### Update destination cell with hyperlink to source cell
        destination_ws.cell(source_cell.row, source_cell.column).hyperlink = hyperlink

### Save new workbook specifying file name
destination_wb.save('foo2.xlsx')
```

###################################################
Change code to put full path to cell...
Instead of adding origin cell and hyperlink to it, set the cell value to the link path. Change the 8 lines from and including

```
### Create hyperlink to source cell
```

to

```
### Set full path to the original cell 
destination_ws.cell(source_cell.row, source_cell.column).value = \
    f'{source_path}#{source_sheet}!{cell_coord}'
```

Comment: Thank you! :) It's very helpful! Do you know how to change the code for getting only values of links in cells? Like in code bellow "This code is for getting the value from a cell from a different file" but for all cells

Comment: The code copies the value from the source first **destination_ws.cell(source_cell.row, source_cell.column).value = source_cell.value** then adds a hyperlink to the cell. If you don't want the value from the source cell then skip that line but ensure something is in the destination cell to click on for the hyperlink unless you want these cells to all have the same display.

Comment: Thank you! I tried and it works but it's not what I exactly need. I Just need to put full path to the cell in the external book. The cell won't have hyperlinks format, just pulling the values from external book

Answer (score 0):

## **moken's** [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74845461/19813684) is more convenient and reliable.

---

This is the code to store **hyperlink** to a cell from a different file:

```
import os

from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook


def main():
    input_workbook_path = r"c:\excel_books\input book.xlsx"
    output_workbook_path = r"c:\excel_books\output book.xlsx"

    input_wb = load_workbook(input_workbook_path)
    output_wb = Workbook()

    sheet_in = input_wb["Sheet1"]
    sheet_out = output_wb["Sheet"]
    cell_index = "B12"
    anchor = "CLICK HERE"

    # =HYPERLINK("[c:\excel_books\input book.xlsx]Sheet1!B12","CLICK HERE")
    external_cell_link = f'=HYPERLINK("[{input_workbook_path}]{sheet_in.title}!{cell_index}", "{anchor}")'

    sheet_out["A2"].value = external_cell_link

    output_wb.save(output_workbook_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code is for getting the **value** from a cell from a different file

```
import os

from openpyxl import load_workbook, utils, Workbook


def construct_link(workbook_absolute_path, sheet_name, cell_index):
    """
    The function onstructs full path to the cell in the external
    book, e.g. - ='c:\excel_books\[input book.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1
    """

    # Adding square brackets arround filename in the path.
    # Before - c:\excel_books\input book.xlsx
    # After - c:\excel_books\[input book.xlsx]
    filename = os.path.basename(workbook_absolute_path)
    dirname = os.path.dirname(workbook_absolute_path)
    full_path = os.path.join(dirname, f"[{filename}]")

    return f"={utils.quote_sheetname(full_path + sheet_name)}!{cell_index}"


def main():
    input_workbook_path = r"c:\excel_books\input book.xlsx"
    output_workbook_path = r"c:\excel_books\output book.xlsx"

    input_wb = load_workbook(input_workbook_path)
    output_wb = Workbook()

    sheet_in = input_wb["Sheet1"]
    sheet_out = output_wb["Sheet"]

    external_cell_link = construct_link(
        input_workbook_path,
        sheet_in.title,
        "C1")

    sheet_out["A2"].value = external_cell_link

    output_wb.save(output_workbook_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This link might be helpful - [Control when external references (links) are updated](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653)

Comment: Thank you! I use the same code for coping cells. I don't need copy the cell's style actually. My goal is to copy cells from one Book and put them like Hyperlinks to another Book. Hyperlinks should link to cells from the first book.

Comment: The code "This code is for getting the value from a cell from a different file" is great! This is what I'm looking for. Do you know how to change this code to copy all cells at once instead one cell like it is implementing in code?

Comment: @Roman, consider using **moken's** [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74845461/19813684) because it is more convenient and reliable.